# How to convert function parameter from Obejctive-C to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I have a question about syntax of function parameter in Swift.

I want to get message through `C` based callback function from library, so I make a function with Objective-C as below:

```
void foo(char *arg) {
    NSLog(@"%s", log);
}
```

Then, I register `foo` to `MainController` interface with Objective-C like this.

```
typedef void (*CB)(char *);
void addFoo(CB func);
...
addFoo(&foo);
```

The above code is a simplified representation, but it print log for library well.

Now, I have to change the language from Objective-C to Swift. Most of the source code has changed, but for the above function, the log is not output normally.

How can I change?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to convert directly. This is code.

```
typealias CB = (String) -> Void
func addCB(cd: CB) {
    // ...
}
func foo(pa: String) {
    // ...
}
var fooFuc: CB = foo(pa: )
addCB(cd: fooFuc)
```

Comment: I want to maintain to use `char *` because the library is only allowed to use that type. If I change to `String`, is it automatically cast well?

Comment: I don't think you need `(pa: )` in the second to last line?

Comment: @Kae10 No, you can only use `CChar` in Swift.

Comment: What is different `CChar` and `Character`? Is it correct syntax `[CChar]` as `char *`?

Comment: @Kae10 In swift, CChar is used for C characters.

Comment: So, could I change `String` to `[CChar]` in your answer for maintenance `char *`?

Comment: @Lumialxk Well, I used `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` instead of `[CChar]` or `String`. It works well. But your answer helps me to define a function format. Thanks about that.